# Can't bind to 'showdatabasedropdown' since it isn't a known property of 'app-searchbox'

Tags: angular

I have a component called, `SearchboxComponent`.

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="searchtd">
        <div class="has-feedback">
          <form class="input-typeahead-form">
            <input [(ngModel)]="input"
                   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                   placeholder="Enter Text"
                   class="form-control"
                   type="text"
                   (click)="dropdownOpen = true"
                   (keydown.escape)="dropdownOpen = false"
                   (blur)="dropdownOpen = false">

            <ux-typeahead #typeahead
                          class="typeahead-example"
                          [(open)]="dropdownOpen"
                          [filter]="input"
                          [options]="loadOptionsFn"
                          [openOnFilterChange]="true"
                          [pageSize]="40"
                          [selectOnEnter]="selectOnEnter"
                          [selectFirst]="selectFirst"
                          [dropDirection]="dropDirection"
                          (optionSelected)="input = $event.option">
            </ux-typeahead>
          </form>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <button type="button" class="m-b btn button-primary">Search</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="showdatabasedropdown">
      <td colspan="3">
        <app-idoldatabasedropdown></app-idoldatabasedropdown>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

The `ts` file for this component is as follows:

```js
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import 'chance';
import { TypeaheadKeyService } from '@ux-aspects/ux-aspects';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TypeAheadService } from 'src/app/search/content/typeahead.service';
import { LoggerService } from 'src/app/common/logging/logger.service';
import { IdoldatabasedropdownComponent } from '../idoldatabasedropdown/idoldatabasedropdown.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-searchbox',
  templateUrl: './searchbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./searchbox.component.css']
})
export class SearchboxComponent {
  @ViewChild(IdoldatabasedropdownComponent)
  values: Array<string> = [];
  showdatabasedropdown = true;
  dropdownOpen = false;
  selectOnEnter = true;
  dropDirection: 'up' | 'down' = 'down';
  selectFirst = true;

  input = '';

  loadOptionsFn = this.loadOptions.bind(this);

  /** Load the options and filter the them */
  loadOptions(pageNum: number, pageSize: number, filter: string): Promise<Array<string>> {

    return this.svcTypeAhead.getTermExpand(filter).pipe(
      tap((array) => console.log('Page: ' + pageNum, 'Filter: ' + filter, array)),
      map((array: string[]) => array.slice(pageNum * pageSize, (pageNum + 1) * pageSize))
    ).toPromise();
  }

  constructor(private svcTypeAhead: TypeAheadService, private logger: LoggerService ) {
  }
}
```

I am using this component in another angular component HTML like so

```html
<app-searchbox></app-searchbox>
```

What I would like to do is set the `showdatabasedropdown`  property in the template itself like

```html
<app-searchbox [showdatabasedropdown]="false"></app-searchbox>
```

However, I am unable to do so because I get the following error.

```
Can't bind to 'showdatabasedropdown' since it isn't a known property of 'app-searchbox'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `@Input()` to mark that property as [input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) property.

Your code should be like:

```js
@Input() showdatabasedropdown = true;
```

Once you decorate the property with `Input` pass the data from the parent template like u just did.